# My feet armature looks off center in pose mode but fine in edit mode. Why?

Tags: edit-mode, pose-mode

When I am in pose mode my feet armature looks like it needs some tweaking but when I go into edit mode it looks ok to me. Why is that? .Blend -----> https://pasteall.org/blend/42eadce5e53d48daa57d90a7e60fc83c

Pose Mode
[image]

Edit Mode
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons here why the bones position is not the same in *Edit* and *Pose* mode.

First off, you've moves the bones in *Pose* mode. To reset select all bones and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset scale and rotation).

The second thing is that IK bones will always point towards their controller (i.e. their *Target*) as soon as you switch to *Pose* mode, you'll see what I mean. For example for the bone called *Angle.L* the target is the bone called *Ankle_IK.L*:

[image]

if you enable and disable the Ik constraints:

[image]

So if you don't want the IK bone to move when you switch into *Pose* mode, you need to correctly align its target in *Edit* mode (or align it to its target):

[image]

Note that as you have a chain of several IK bones you'll need to do it for all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much!